# NPM Command Not Found

Tags: node.js, bash, npm

I just updated node (through the nodejs.org package installer) and now `npm` won't work.

`npm: command not found`

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: Which OS and version are you using?

Comment: What is the output of `which npm`?

Comment: You may need to find the full path to the where the updated npm command was installed.

Comment: @Salem, /usr/local/bin/npm

Comment: Is `/usr/local/bin` in your `$PATH`?

Comment: download new nodejs pkg and installing fix the problem too.

Comment: @RameshShrestha thanks! I did a lot of fruitless futzing around until I saw your suggestion which worked for me. It had the extra benefit of updating my fairly out of date version of node.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was hung up on this too.  I installed node via nvm and could not run npm or node.  I had to run `nvm use 0.10.10`

then `which node` and `which npm` worked again.

if you have installed `npm` via `nvm` you might want to add `nvm use <version>` to your `.bashrc` file so that you'll have `npm` always available on any shell you open. You just need to remember to update it whenever you update npm, or use `stable`.

Answer (score 3):

It could be a permission issue as well. If so you need to run this: sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local

This worked for me

Comment: Do you have a solution for windows too?